# Distributing data from a list into to multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a list of item codes in a column (changes in a day) which needs to be distributed to a different sheet and in multiple columns (depending on number of agents available in a day).

To have a better illustration, please see this screenshot: [image: Item codes.png]

Then it needs to be distributed to this: [image: Database.png].

What could be the best formula or even VBA syntax for this?

Comment: your first screenshot contains numbers, the second one names, it's a bit confusing:( Is that the same data? Have your tried paste special - transposing?

Comment: Before we can think of an answer one information is needed, how exactly do you assign one document ID to an agent?
is there any relations or it doesn't matter? It seams it depends on how many agents are available in a day so is it like this :
say you have 240 documents and 24 agents, each one of them gets 10 docs ? how many documents max in a day?

Comment: @Máté JuhásZ seconnd image is the sheet where the documents from image #1 will be distrubuted. Meaning the total documents from the first image will be distributed in each name on the second image

Comment: please post desired output instead of the second picture, it would make a lot easier to understand your question.

Comment: Automatic distribution of total document to another sheet. Total document should be divided to how many available agents for the day. Then the result will be displayed to the second image below the names of the agents. A command button can be added to perform this action.

Comment: For example we have 240 documents for the day. It should be equally  divided to 10 agents available which names are shown in the second image. Then the results should show on the part or below the name of agents

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a way to tag the agents that are not available and calculate an index for each cell.

I added two rows above the agent labels, the first allows agents to be tagged as not available.  I added some conditional formatting to cell colour and strike out the name of unavailable agents.

The other is a helper row which is a incremental index for available agents of the form `=IF(9:9="",MAX($C8:C8)+1,"-")`

I also added a helper column which is just the row index starting at 0.   (The helper columns could be directly incorporated into the table formula but it makes it harder to read.  The helper row and column can obviously be hidden).

The formula in the table just uses a simple  `=INDEX(<docs_id_list>,MATCH(..,<docs_id_index_list>,0))` formula.

The table formula is 
`=IFERROR(INDEX('Document List'!$B:$B,MATCH($A:$A*(COUNTA($C$10:$P$10)-COUNTIFS($C$9:$P$9,"<>"))+$8:$8,'Document List'!$A:$A,0)),"-")`

(which obviously assumes your document list is in columns A & B of a sheet called "Document List")

[image]

My solution uses a simple first-in/first-out formula but it would be possible to adjust the formula using the weekday number to start the allocation at a different cell so table is biased towards the agents in the left hand column.